# BIRT How to correctly chart date time axis with sparse data

Tags: date, charts, birt

I have a query that returns a count of events on dates over the last year.

e.g.

```
|Date       | ev_count|
------------+----------
|2015-09-23 |    12   |
|2016-01-01 |    56   |
|2016-01-15 |    34   |
|2016-04-08 |    65   | 
| ...
```

I want to produce a graph (date on the X-axis and value on Y) that will either show values for all dates (0 when no data), or at least place the dates where there are values in a correctly scaled place for the date along the time axis.

My current graph has just the values one after another. I have previously used dimple for generating graphs, and if you tell it that it's a time axis, it automagically places dates correctly spaced.

```
 This is what I get
|
|         *
|   *   
|      *
|*_______________
 9  1  1  4


 This is what I want to have
|
|                                        *
|                         *   
|                            *
|_________*________________________________________
 0    0    1    1    1    0    0    0    0   .....
 8    9    0    1    2    1    2    3    4
```

Is there a function/trick in BIRT that will allow me to fill in the gaps with 0 or position/scale the date somehow (e.g. based on a max/min)? Or do I have to join my data with a date generator query to fill in the gaps?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: I went with a generated calendar to join on. I created a calendar table similar to https://gist.github.com/bryhal/4129042. You can then select dates and Left join with your query and thus get 0/Null values for dates with no data.